# Japanese text break lines correctly: What's the difference between `word-break:keep-all`, `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow-wrap:break-word`?

Tags: css, cjk, word-break, kanji

In HTML and CSS, how do I make japanese text break lines correctly?

I like to use the CSS `word-break:keep-all` on my websites to stop Japanese kanji being broken in a weird way but what is the difference between `word-break:keep-all`, `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow-wrap:break-word` when using Japanese text?

```html
<p style="word-break:keep-all">日本語, 漢字, ご返事, 文字, お寿司, 漢字, また, 文字, 日本語, 漢字, また, 文字, グレン</p>
```

Comment: Why do you not want to break kanji? That's the normal thing to do and that's exactly where the difference is: `normal` breaks only CJK words and not latin ones.

Comment: Sometimes Japanese words are split is weird ways like: 日本 on one line and 語 on the second line, at the end of a list. I'm not a sure why this happens but think it always looks better when the words are not split. I realize Japanese is a language that doesn't need spaces at times but have always been looking for a way to control where the splits happen. I'm happy to use any CSS but I'm not sure what the best option is. Any help here is greatly appreciated.